# How to insert a div between a top and bottom div on opposite side?

Tags: css, html

[image: Required layout]

I would like to place the right `div` between the left and bottom `div`s. The width must be 40% for each. I'm trying to do this without Javascript.

```
#left_col,#right_col,#bottom {
    width: 40%;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    padding: 0;
    border: #0BDC00 solid 2px;
}
#right_col{
   float:right;
   clear:right;
   text-align: right;
   display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Please always include what you have tried so far.

Comment: What do you mean by "place the Right div between the left and bottom divs"? D you mean as markup, or via JS/jQuery on a click event or what?

Comment: as you can see on the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `clear:left` and `clear:right` use `clear:both` instead;

```
#left_col,#right_col,#bottom {
    width: 40%;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    padding: 0;
    border: #0BDC00 solid 2px;
}
#right_col{
   float:right;
   clear:both;
   text-align: right;
   display:table-cell;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wk4psg2p/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: #F72F4E;
}

.Container {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.Row {
  display: flex;
}

.Row:nth-of-type(odd) {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.Row:nth-of-type(even) {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.Row__item {
  width: 40%;
  background: #000;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Row">
    <div class="Row__item">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Row">
    <div class="Row__item">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Row">
    <div class="Row__item">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```